# React: scrollIntoView on componentDidMount using refs

Tags: reactjs, ref, js-scrollintoview

I am rendering a Dialog component with a lot of text and the dialog has therefore a scroll. Text contains some links, and the content of the Dialog changes when a link is clicked. The problem is, when the content changes, the scroll stays in the same position at the height of the link. I would like to scroll to the top of the dialog when the new content is displayed.

I have created a class component for the Dialog content and implemented the handleTop function that uses refs and scrollIntoView to scroll to the top of the Dialog. When this function is called from a Button click event (TestButton), then the content is scrolled to the top. However when this function is called from the componentDidMount(), nothing happens.

```
export default class DialogContent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.myRef=React.createRef();
}

handleTop = () => {
  this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'start'
    });  
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      this.handleTop(); 
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
            <h1 ref={this.myRef}>Title</h1>
            <p>A lot of text</p>
            <Button>TestButton</Button>
    <div>
)
}
```

I also verified that the componentDidMount function gets called by placing a console.log message.

Any ideas or suggestions would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: I tested it and seems to work fine. Is it possible, that when you load the page, it's already "scrolled up", and therefore nothing happens on componentDidMount?

Comment: No; I put a link on the end of the first page and it's scrolled way down; when I click the link and display the new page, the content changes but the scroll remains at the same position (in the middle of the new page, since the new page has more content)

Comment: Can you upload your entire working code to some playground or github?

Comment: While I was preparing the example I resolved the issue; The link I used in the text to change the content was causing the problem. When I changed the Link component, the code started working as expected...Thank's for your support